# PHP data normalization on array importer?

Tags: php, arrays, normalization

Is it possible to data normalization directly on csv importer array?
I have the following:

```
          foreach($importData_arr as $importData){
           // var_dump($importData);
            $insertData = array(
               "EAN"=>$importData[0], preg_replace('\'', '', "EAN"),
               "Brand"=>$importData[1],
               "Name"=>$importData[2],
               "Size"=>$importData[3],
               "PCD"=>$importData[4],
               "Offset"=>$importData[5],
               "Bore"=>$importData[6],
               "Color"=>$importData[7],
               "Price"=>$importData[8],
               "Stock"=>$importData[9],
               "ImageURL"=>$importData[10]);
            RimsUpload::insertData($insertData);
```

But i recerive the error :
preg_replace(): No ending delimiter ''' found

This `\'` should allow for searching for `'` and replacing with `'nothing'` in my EAN column, as far as i know. But i am not sure that its possible directly on the array like this?

Comment: Your regex needs delimiters, try `preg_replace('/\'/', '', "EAN")`

Comment: @Nick `str_replace` is enough here.

Comment: @u_mulder agreed, but just trying to point out what is causing OPs error. If I was posting an answer I would definitely say that.

Comment: Well, i would think str_replace would be enough too.. but apparently it wont accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's **no need** for regular expressions when you want to replace one symbol, `str_replace` will do th job.

Also, `preg_replace('\'', '', "EAN")`, **even** with correct delimiters, (e.g. `#`):

```
preg_replace('#\'#', '', "EAN")
```

will return string `EAN`.

Obviously, you want to replace `'` in `$importData[0]` value.

So your code should be:

```
$insertData = array(
    "EAN" => str_replace('\'', '', $importData[0]),
    "Brand"=>$importData[1],
    "Name"=>$importData[2],
    "Size"=>$importData[3],
    "PCD"=>$importData[4],
    // ...
```

And if you still want to use regular expressions (which is redundant here), then provide [correct delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), e.g.:

```
$insertData = array(
    "EAN" => preg_replace('#\'#', '', $importData[0]),
    "Brand"=>$importData[1],
    "Name"=>$importData[2],
    "Size"=>$importData[3],
    "PCD"=>$importData[4],
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpfull answer. works like a charm with : "EAN" => str_replace('\'', '', $importData[0]), and great to know how to use regex too, as i will be needing that on some other fields later on :-)